# understanding max_feature in random forest

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

I got a question when training the forest. I used a 5-fold cross validation and rmse as guideline to figure out the best parameter for the model. I eventually find that when the max_feature=1, I got the smallest rmse. That's strange to me, since max_feature is the feature considered at each split. Generally, if I want to find the "best" parameter to lowest the impurity in splitting, the tree should, at best, consider all the features and find the one result in lowest impurity after splitting. However, in terms of the cross validation, I get max_feature=1 to be lowest the rmse. Is that due to the more feature considered, the lower generality the tree becomes? Thanks

Comment: I don't get the down-votes. It is a relevant question that could baffle many

Comment: @CutePoison yeah right. Was wondering the same. Upvoted the question to void the downvote.

Comment: Same here - I had a very similar question when writing my masters. It is not trivial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the idea of a random forest is, that a single Decision Tree has a large variance but a low bias (it is overfitting). We then create different trees to reduce that variance

Let `X_i` be the trees in the forest. Assume each tree is i.d with mean `mu` and variance `sigma`, and let the prediction be of the mean of all `X_i`. We assume that all X's are not independent (since they share some of the same training data and the same features) and positive correlated with some constant `p`. We can write the variance of the mean (the prediction) as :

[image]

where `n` is the number of trees.

Since everything but `p` is fixed you want to reduce `p` as much as possible i.e the correlation between trees and if you use all the same features for each split it is very likely that you end up with some correlated ("identical" trees) thus a high variance (eventhough you CV it).

With that in mind it is not strange that `max_feature=1` is the optimal choice since the trees grown are very unlikely to be identical (or alike).

It is just the classic "bias-variance trade-off".

EDIT: The proof for the formular

[image]

[image]

Comment: So would you recommend NOT using max_feature = 1 during hyperparameter tuning?

Comment: No, it just makes sense that you can have a small RMSE (I assume it is a regression-tree) even with max_feature=1, since you lower the variance. If the data has difficulties describing the target e.g try model a fair coin-toss, you would need some "simple" model (average, median etc.) since everything else would overfit heavily.

Comment: That totally makes sense. Thanks a lot

Comment: Could you give more hints on how do you get this formula? thanks

Comment: Have added it to the answer