# svm takes long time for hyperparameter tuning

Tags: classification, svm, logistic-regression, random-forest

I am running SVM,Logistic Rregression and Random Forest on the [credit card dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/janiobachmann/credit-fraud-dealing-with-imbalanced-datasets/execution). My training dataset has the shape (454491, 30). I performed 5-fold cross validation(which took more than an hour) with 'scoring' set as 'f1_weighted' and got the below results:

```
Logistic Regression Cross Validation F1 score: 0.9501631748525725
Random Forest Cross Validation F1 score: 0.9999383944188953
Support Vector Cross Validation F1 score: 0.9989703035983751
```

I chose SVM as Random Forest is prone to overfitting and SVM scored better than Logistic Regression.

I wanted to add **regularization** by hyperparameter tuning. I initially used GridSearchCV but it was taking a long time so I changed it to RandomizedSearchCV but even this is taking a very long time (around 4-5+ hours). According to the data description, the features have been scaled and PCA has been performed to preserve the private information. I have also used RobustScaler() on Amount and Time columns as they were not scaled.

```
tuned_parameters={"kernel":['rbf','sigmoid'],
                 'gamma':[1e-2, 1e-3, 1e-4, 1e-5],
                 'C':[0.001, 0.10, 0.0001,0.00001]}


tuned_SVM=RandomizedSearchCV(SVC(),tuned_parameters,cv=3,scoring='f1_weighted',random_state=12,verbose=15,n_jobs=-1)
```

Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First** of all; the idea of Random Forest is to *reduce overfitting*. It is correct that at single Decision Tree is (very often) very overfit- that is why we create this ensemble to reduce the variance but still keep the bias low.  Note that the variance of the Random Forest (overfitting) can vary heavily on your parameters e.g if you set `max_features=n_features` where `n_features` is the number of features, you will just create a multiple of the same decision trees which will indeed lead to overfitting.

My point is here, that Random Forest can be a strong tool and a *decision tree* is heavily overfitting while *random forest* (should) not.

**Secondly**; if I recall correctly, the training time of SVM is O(n^2) where `n` is the number of training points i.e when having a lot of training data it can take a long time to fit thus grid-searching over the parameters can take a long (!) time.

**Third**; regarding regularization. If you have had a 0.99 val-score using a kernel (assume it is "rbf") I would just run with the "rbf" kernel and just tune the `C`-parameter due to the training-time of SVM. Also, aren't 0.998 good enough?

Decision Trees can be regularized using "cost complexity pruning" where you, just in logistic regression, penalize the scoring function with the complexity (depth of tree). I don't think Random Forest (sklearn) have that option.
Their Decision Trees have, so you can build your own Random Forest from that but since you have the `max_depth` parameter in the Random Forest I don't think that is worth it.

**Fourth**; Consider [bayesian optimization](https://medium.com/vantageai/bringing-back-the-time-spent-on-hyperparameter-tuning-with-bayesian-optimisation-2e21a3198afb)

Why do you want to use SVM when Random Forest is (according to your results) performing better and is faster to train?

Comment: I did use Random Forest initially. I wanted to add regularization so I tried changing different hyper-parameter values using GridSearchCV and RandomSearchCV but that took a long time. Then I decided to try out SVM and I wanted to perform hyper-parameter optimization but since it was taking so long and  the cross val score is pretty good(0.998), I decided to add regularization by changing the C parameter and gamma parameter using GridSearchCV and RandomSearchCV which also took a very long time.

Comment: Regularization is used to avoid overfitting. Random Forest reduces over-fitting  "by nature". Why does it have to be regularization in SVM that is your final model when RF performs so well?

Comment: I ended up using the svm package from cuML  and using Bayesian optimization to tune the hyper parameters. For Random Forests, to add regularization I was changing the n_estimators,max_features,max_depth and min_samples_leaf hyperparameters using GridSearchCV and RandomSearchCV which is probably why it took so long. I;ll try doing the same with Bayesian optimization and see if it makes a difference

Comment: Being an ensemble method, RF does tackle overfitting better than decision trees but I've read cases where it does overfit: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/1028/do-random-forest-overfit. So I thought adding regularization would help if it is overfitting

Comment: That is not correct - RF has the same bias (theoretically) as a decison tree, but the ensemble help reduces the variance thus the overfitting. See the proof in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63406684/understanding-max-feature-in-random-forest/63406888#63406888

Comment: Makes sense but as you mentioned before that it heavily relies on max_features. Having a high value for max_features causes the trees to be more correlated, and therefore limits the variance reduction and might cause some overfitting. I'll try running the RF on the test set to see if it is overfitting. If it does, I'll try reducing the max_features.

Comment: My mistake, I read it as "RF does not handle overfitting". It surely can overfit like all algorithms